# How to keep your distributed cache clean?

Tags: caching, redis, appfabric

In a N-Tier architecture, what would be the best patterns to use so that you can keep your cache clean?

I know it's easy to just set an absolute/sliding timeout, but is there a better mechanism available to allow you to mark your cache as dirty after you update the underlying persistence.

The difficulty I"m trying to wrap my head around is that Cache are usually stored as KVP. But a query is usually a fair bit more complex than that. So how can the gateway service tell the cache store that for such and such query, it needs to refetch from persistence.

I also can't afford to hand-code the cache update per query. I'm looking for a more systematic approach.

Is this just a pipe dream, or is there some way to do this elegantly?

Link/Guide/Post appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked with AppFabric and I think tried to do what you are asking about. I was working on an auction site and I wanted to pro-actively invalidate items in the cache.

For example, we had listings (things for sale) and they would be present all over the cache (AppFabric). The data that represented a listing was in 10 different places. What I initially wanted was a way to say, "Ok, my listing has changed. Let me go find everywhere it exists in cache, and then update." (I think you say "mark as dirty" in your question)

I found doing this was incredibly difficult. There are tags in AppFabric that I tried to use, so I would mark a given object (or collection of objects) with a tag and that would let me query the cache and remove items. In other words, if an object had a LISTING tag, I would find it and invalidate it.

Eventually I settled on a two-pronged attack.

1. For 95% of the data I let it expire. It was a happy day when I decided this because everything got much easier to develop. I had to make some concessions in the UI etc., but it was well worth it.
2. For the last 5% of the data I resolved to only ever store it once. For example, a bid on a listing. Whenever a new bid came in, we'd pro-actively invalidate that object, and then everything that needed that information would be updated as well.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like a really plausible strategy.